# Return value of threshold function in opencv

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I am applying Otsu threshold method using opencv 2.4.9 function 'threshold'

As per opencv documentation:

> The special value THRESH_OTSU may be combined with one of the above values. In this case, the function determines the optimal threshold value using the Otsu’s algorithm and uses it instead of the specified thresh . The function returns the computed threshold value. Currently, the Otsu’s method is implemented only for 8-bit images.

For my test image function is returning value of 49.

1. What does 49 signify?
2. How can I use it for further thresholding operation like masking rows which are having no of white pixels less than threshold?

Comment: How can you have "white pixels less than threshold"?

Comment: I am using Binary image obtained from opencv threshold function.

Answer (score 0):

The value 49 means thresholding your image with the threshold 49 would give you the best result based on the otsu method.
If I've understood your second question correctly the way to applying this 49 value for threshold is to iterate through the grayscale image pixel by pixel and assigning 0 to pixels having intensity above 49 and assigning 255 to those having intensity below 49 or vice versa.

Comment: So does this mean I need to apply thresholding operation other than Otsu after getting threshold, as opencv function ignores 3rd arg i.e. threshold when it is Otsu thresholding?

Comment: Also, for second question tried two way to use threshold value returned as follow:
1. As suggested by Amen, counted no of pixels per row and masked those rows which are having no of white pixels less than threshold.
2. Considering threshold as indication of row which can be utilized to count no. of white pixels to be used for thresholding operation. (Not sure if understanding is correct)
Second approach resulted in better identification of edges than first one.

Comment: thresholding is a technique for identifying regions of a "Gray Scale", in a gray scale image each pixel has one value between 0-255 in contrast with RGB picture that each pixel has 3 values each one representing one of the three colors, so after getting the otsu number you need to threshold each pixel as described in the answer. now what do you mean by white pixels?

Comment: Thaks for clarification, I think I am using same logic. About white pixels, I am using opencv threshold function to convert Gray image to binary image where only Black and white pixels are there.
Here is call to threshold:
threshold(grayImage, grayImage, 0, 255,                                        CV_THRESH_BINARY | CV_THRESH_OTSU);

Comment: and what happens after that? you should expect to see a binary image after thresholding which contains only whit and black colors.

Comment: Yes I am getting binary image. return value of threshold is 49 which I am using for further masking of white pixels as explained in earlier post. Posted question as I was not sure what this threshold indicates and how to use that.

Comment: If you already have the binary image then there is no other thing to do! thresholding results in a binary image. I haven't used open cv, I usually work in matlab but as you described the function is filtering the image into a binary image via the 42 value for threshold, what else do you want to get?

Comment: Main purpose is to do edge detection, horizontal edge detection in particular. For this I am converting gray scale image into binary image with Otsu method. Even after there are some white pixels visible which are not to be considered as edge and I wan mask them out with black pixels. To do this iterating the image row wise and calculating no. of white pixels and if this number is less than threshold, setting all pixels in that row to black. So, was thinking what thresold returned by opencv threshold indicates and if somehow I can utilize it to mask non-edge white pixels.

Comment: Found this link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otsu's_method explaining about Otsu method. It seems threshold indicates variance value computed by algorithm, but not sure how to utilize it :(